Looking for a movie about a child-like alien?
I rented this movie (or rather my parents rented) from a local video store when I was a kid. It's either late seventies or an eighties movie and all I can remember is rather vague!   
There's this child who is being hunted by some mysterious dudes going around in suits, ties and sunglasses - very official looking - could be FBI or similar, not sure why they're after him but I think its because he's an alien! Anyway, this child is befriended by a large bearded man (I think he had a beard) and I think he's some sort of policeman. He's also being menaced by a large group of crazy looking bikers who wear outlandish outfits and are constantly getting their asses kicked by this policeman. I suppose you could kind of call it a cross between ET and Any Which Way But Loose if you can imagine such a thing!!!   
I have not dreamt this by the way as my dad can remember renting out the same movie time and time again!

As pointed out by Mario, this seems like the Bud Spencer action comedy Chissà perché capitano tutte a me from 1980 (the sequel to 'Uno sceriffo extraterrestre' from 1979) about a grizzled, bearded sheriff (Spencer) helping out an alien child. This sequel is available here on Youtube (and so is the original movie).

Also important to mention that there's a sequel as well (Chissà perché... capitano tutte a me), so even if it's just similar it might be the other movie.

Good point, it seems very similar. The sequel is also available online here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vU1lsnvdrQk

Actually, I'm like 100% sure the wez is talking about one of both movies, I just don't remember which one had that rocker gang in it. I think it might actually have been the second one.

I think you're right - I skimmed the sequel on Youtube and there are definitely some weird bikers in there. I think you should put it up as the answer (should I delete mine?)

No, just update yours and add that new knowledge.

Wow! Thanks dudes! Must be 30 years since I saw this film and within an hour I get a response!!! I'm quite impressed I remember a fair bit about it. I remember the music now and also those weird robots with the sunglasses in the sequel! A sequel as well??? I must've seen both then and former boxer Joe Bugner in it as well!!! I've found the English versions on youtube, the first one is called "The Sheriff and the Satellite Kid and the sequel is bizarrely called "Why Did You Pick On Me?"

@wet Don't forget to accept this answer if it was the correct solution to your problem.

It's one of those classics. It might be old, but I'm still watching it every time (like pretty much all movies with Bud :)). Just timeless classics. Also, if you're capable of understanding German, try the German dubs. They're awesome and often add even more flavor/awesome stuff (especially the western movies with Spencer and Hill).

Glad to see I'm not the only Bud Spencer fan around here :)

Meh, I used to watch them quite often as a child, but at some point I just grew out of them and they're airing them to death here on TV anyway (still there are some rare pearls, like the Aladdin movie).

@NapoleonWilson - My favorite has to be "Buddy Goes West".

Could it be Mac and Me from 1988?


Welcome to Movies & TV! I'm afraid this question was already answered correctly above (it just wasn't marked as such). Also, please try to briefly explain why you think your answers are correct or add a short synopsis.
